# Visualizing and manipulating 4-dimensional data with 3D technology

Tags: 3d, visualization

It is possible to visualize 3 dimensional data (like a scatter plot) by projecting it on a 2 dimensional screen in a way that allows to interact with it in an intuitive way.

Is it possible to visualize 4 dimensional data (like a scatter plot) by projecting it on a *virtual 3D space* in a way that allows to interact with it in an intuitive way or *at least in a fashion that one can get used to*?

Comments on the italic written wordings:

- 'virtual 3D space' means a 3D space created in your brain by suggesting a different perspective to your eyes by means of shutter goggles for example.
- 'in a fashion that one can get used to' is adressing the fact that the projection of a 3D space onto a 2D space uses concepts from 3 dimensional vision like perspective, blurred edges, shadows, ... such concepts are not trivially applicable when going from 3D to 4D.

Comment: Not intended to be an answer, but… how do you define a “projection”? When I visualized quaternion multiplication, [I resorted to a bizarre and clumsy pseudo-3D presentation of S³](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Versor_action_on_Hurwitz_quaternions.svg), but I feel it offers more insight than, say, orthogonal projections from ℍ to ℝ³ could.